# sqlalchemy mapper event issue

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Ii defined the following classes in sqlalchemy:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    userId = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = Column(String(60), unique=True,nullable=False)
    userName = Column(Unicode(16),unique=True)
    _password = Column('password', Unicode(60))
    groups = relationship("Group",secondary='userGroup') 
    profile = relationship("UserProfile",uselist=False,backref='user') 

class Group(Base):
        __tablename__ = 'group'
        groupId = Column(Integer,
                       Sequence('group_id_seq', optional=True),
                       primary_key=True)
        groupName = Column(Unicode(255), unique=True)

UserGroupTable = Table('userGroup', Base.metadata,
        Column('userId', Integer, ForeignKey(User.userId)),
        Column('groupId', Integer, ForeignKey(Group.groupId))
    )


class UserProfile(Base):
    __tablename__='userProfile'
    userId = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.userId'), primary_key=True)
    dateJoin = Column(Date,nullable=False,default=func.current_date())
    gender = Column(Integer)
```

The `user` is in a many-to-many relationship with `group` and when I initialised the tables, I added two groups 'user' and 'admin' as below. The problem is that when I use the mapper event to add a user to 'user' group when insert, it does not work:

```
def before_insert_user_listener(mapper,connection,target):
    session=DBSession()
    ug=session.query(Group).filter(Group.groupName=='user').first()
    target.groups.append(ug)    
    target.profile=UserProfile()
    log.debug(">>>>>")

def initialize_sql(engine):
    DBSession.configure(bind=engine)
    Base.metadata.bind = engine
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
    try:
        session = DBSession()
        #event register
        event.listen(User,'before_insert',before_insert_user_listener)
        group1 = Group('admin')
        group2 = Group('user') 
        session.add(group1)
        session.add(group2)           
        transaction.commit()
    except IntegrityError:
        pass
```

When i try to add a new user, the user is added, and I can see the log print from the event listener, but the user is not added to the 'user' group. I also tried the 'after_insert' event, but it also didn't work.

Edit: I add the userProfile table which is a one-to-one relationship to user,and a user profile can be create with default join date in above before_insert event. add user to group still not working though.

What did I miss?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you really store the groups in the database on `transaction.commit()`? I do not see them added to the `session`.

Comment: ah..actually they're added.. i was removing unrelative code and deleted those lines by mistake. just added. thanks for pointing out.

Comment: I guess it is, but please ensure that `DBSession()` in test code and the event listener is actually the same session. If it is not - you found the reason and you can use `object_session` to get the proper one in the listener.

Comment: I tried session=object_session(target), but result is same

Comment: are you sure groups are saved in the db? check if **ug** is not None in the listener above...

Comment: yes. i'm sure groups are saved in the db and ug is not None in the listener. actually when add log msg like:

log.debug("About to Add New User:\n %s %s %s" % (target,str(target.groups),str(target.profile))) 

to above listener, i can see the target.groups is 'user' groups, but it just don't get in to db. 

anyway. i've work around this by doing it right after the user insert code. and it works well. thanks for your help anyway.:-)

Answer (score 1):

As the extract from the [before_insert](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/interfaces.html?highlight=before_insert#sqlalchemy.orm.interfaces.MapperExtension.before_insert) documentation suggests:

> Column-based attributes can be modified within this method which will
>   result in the new value being inserted. However **no changes** to the
>   overall flush plan can be made, and manipulation of the Session will
>   not have the desired effect. To manipulate the Session within an
>   extension, use SessionExtension.

from which I conclude that one cannot add new objects to the session which is being commited/flushed or add/set relationships.

I guess the better way would be to listen to [before_commit](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.SessionEvents.before_commit) or [before_flush](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/docs/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.SessionEvents.before_flush) session event, check all new `User` objects and adding them to the `User` group. For example:

```
def my_before_commit(session):
    g=session.query(Group).filter(Group.groupName=='user').one()
    for target in session:
        if isinstance(target, User) and target in session.new:
            target.groups.append(ug)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply van. I just tried before_commit event. it does not add a user to 'user' group neither. however the strange thing is another relationship i added for user table ,the userProfile, works with 'before_insert' and 'after_insert'(i added to my post above). I'm starting to doubt my schema design...